# Leonard Nimoy Cameo in Super 8

Tags: cameo, super-8

According to the following article, **Leonard Nimoy**, an actor like many has worked with JJ Abrams on other Bad Robot Productions, has an un-credited **cameo** in the film ***Super 8***.

[image: Walter Bishop & William Bell]

> J.J. Abrams has revealed that actor Leonard Nimoy appears in Super 8.
>
> In an interview with Collider, Abrams stated that there are a number
>   of hidden features in the highly secretive movie, including the Star
>   Trek actor.
>
> "Leonard Nimoy is in the movie somewhere if you can find him," Abrams
>   said.
>   http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/star-trek/news/a323471/jj-abrams-leonard-nimoy-is-in-super-8/

I have never been able to find the cameo and was wondering if anyone has ever found it/knows where it is?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this blog post](http://collwrites.com/2011/06/12/you-bet-i-spent-the-night-searching-fo-super-8-easter-eggs/), his name appears on a can that a character holds in the "home video".

The part of the post says:

> Also, thanks queequeg for point out that the Leonard Nimoy “cameo” in Super 8 
>   was the name Nimoy appearing on a can one of the characters holds in the home 
>   video.  If we see it again, I’ll be on the look out for it!

Comment: Cool, Thanks. I'll have to watch the scene sometime soon. I'm going to wait to mark yours as the answer, since I am not sure if this is what Abram's meant, --is name of a person still considered an "appearance"? I just will wait a bit to see if any other answers emerge. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There was a picture of the TOS cast on a wall in one of the kids' bedroom.  I'm pretty sure it was in the "movie within the movie" but I'm not positive.  I'll see if I can get a screen shot and attach it to my answer.

Nimoy himself, as a live actor, was not in the movie.

Comment: Thanks That would be great! Maybe after all he is not "live" in the movie, but IMO Abrams words would suggest otherwise when he uses says, "he's in the movie." I just don't think he would of even of brought it up, if it was just an image or a name of Nimoy, but, at the same time, no one has ever found him so who knows?! Simon Pegg is  even technically in the movie, playing motion capture for some of the Argus scenes.